# Running into issues when trying to run OpenAssistant locally with chat

Tags: docker, macos, artificial-intelligence

I was able to get OpenAssistant running locally without chat just fine, however I'm encountering main issues when trying to run locally with chat. I was able to switch Dockerfile.worker-full to Dockerfile.worker-standalone in the docker compose config, but I'm still getting issues, and I'm getting an error ""failed to solve: process "/bin/sh -c pip install --cache-dir=/var/cache/pip --target=lib -r requirements.txt" when trying to run dev locally with chat. The attachment to this issue can hopefully outline my problems
[image]

If anyone can help me, it'd be great. I'm running OpenAssistant on an M1 MacBook and the platform in my docker compose config is "linux/x86_64".

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible to run the worker on M1. Need a Nvidia GPU. The images are built with that requirement. The backend and other services can be run ofcourse